# how can i create new region in theme?

Tags: theming

I just want to create a new region in my theme on the top right side of page.
with height = 50 px and width=200 px

i'm using drupal version 7

Answer (score 1):

First you need to define region in your_theme.info https://drupal.org/node/171205#regions

for example

```
regions[search_bar]         = Top Search bar
```

then you probably want to output that region in your page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print render($page['search_bar']); ?>
```

to make it height = 50 px and width=200 px you need to write some css. You can also add some wrapping div with id:

```
<?php if ($page['search_bar']): ?>
<div id="search-bar">
    <?php print render($page['search_bar']); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```